# PDF from UIWebview sent to apps in "Open In..." Menu

Tags: ios

Is it possible to send a file being displayed in an UIWebview to another app using a button to display the "Open In..." menu?

Answer (score 1):

there needs to be a local copy of the file to use the `UIDocumentInteractionController` methods of displaying an "Open In" menu that lists any app that registers for that file type. So you could download the file, display the file from your local area using `UIWebView` and then have it ready to go for a `UIDocumentInteractionController` take a look at its docs for more info [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)